# Как связать правильно таблицы mysql?

Tags: mysql

MySQL версии 5.7.20.

Не получается связать таблицы. Нужно чтобы в таблице categories, были связаны поля id и parent_id. Нужно выводить название категории. Как правильно сформировать запрос?
Вот мой запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN categories AS i1 ON products.id_category = i1.id 
LEFT JOIN categories as i2 ON i2.parent_id = i1.id;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Как выводится список товаров]
[image: Таблица с товарами]

Comment: *Нужно выводить название категории.* Какой именно? Непосредственной? её родительской? обеих? Данные в таблице категорий - строго 2 уровня, или может быть больше? если больше - нужно ли всё дерево категорий? PS. для строго двух уровней запрос правильный, если не считать звезды в списке полей вывода. PPS. Укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: 5.7.20 версия. Нужно выводить категорию и подкатегорию товара. Этим запросом я вывожу в админке список всех товаров, которые имеются в базе.  Нужно чтобы в графе категория, была категория, у которой parent_id = 0. И его подкатегория. Все, где parent_id = 0 это категории.

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос *Данные в таблице категорий - строго 2 уровня, или может быть больше?*. Это важно. *Нужно выводить категорию и подкатегорию товара.* Как именно? в одном поле? в двух полях? Покажите пример желаемого вывода для одного товара.

Comment: Я добавил две картинки. Таблица с товарами (products) и как выводятся в админке товары. Пока меню будет только двухуровневое. То есть основные категории и подкатегории.

Comment: *Пока меню будет только двухуровневое. То есть основные категории и подкатегории.* Если количество уровней в будущем увеличится, для вашей версии MySQL запрос придётся переделывать самым радикальным образом - а скорее всего вообще реализовывать вывод хранимой процедурой. И лучше, наверное, об этом задуматься прямо сейчас...

Comment: Я только учусь)) Это тренировка просто) И честно говоря я не понял, что вы сказали) Я этого еще не знаю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для строго двухуровневой системы категорий:

```
SELECT p.name,
       i1.name subcategory,
       i2.name category 
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN categories AS i1 ON products.id_category = i1.id 
LEFT JOIN categories as i2 ON i1.parent_id = i2.id
```

Если каждый продукт гарантированно имеет ссылку на существующую подкатегорию, а та столь же гарантированно имеет ссылку на категорию (поддержано внешними ключами), LEFT JOIN заменить на INNER JOIN.

Comment: Unknown column 'i1.name' in 'field list'. Ошибку такую выдает.

Comment: @Roman Вероятно, у Вас это поле имеет другое имя. Исправьте.

Comment: это я исправил уже. Только вместо названия категории и подкатегории выводятся id их.

Comment: Все разобрался) Благодарю.